# url containing "&" does not work with google pagespeed api

Tags: javascript, google-pagespeed

i am using Google pagespeed API to test urls of my site. it works fine as long as url structure doesn't contain any "&" (query string parameters) .

**examples which (Works)**

1. http://www.example.com
2. http://www.example.com/?id=1234

But when i change url something like this, then it doesn't show correct result

**Example which Does not Works**

1) http://www.example.com/?id=1234&sub=890

Api ignores the "&sub=890" part and returns the result for http://www.example.com/?id=1234

**Looking at API Javascript Code:**

```
 function runPagespeed() {        
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.async = true;
        var query = [
            'url=' + URL_TO_GET_RESULTS_FOR,
            'strategy=' + strategy,
            'callback=runPagespeedCallbacks',
            'key=' + API_KEY,
        ].join('&');
        s.src = API_URL + query;
        document.head.insertBefore(s, null);
    }
```

So looking at this function it shows that API will treat "sub=890" as its own parameter so it will ignore it.

When i use the url http://www.example.com/?id=1234&sub=890  on  https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ , it works fine and shows the Result

Note: I am using pagespeed sample code for testing which is https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v2/first-app

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: perhaps `.join('&amp;')`

Comment: .join('&amp;')  does not work :(

Comment: Well, `sub=890` shouldn't need any encoding, but in your code you have a full URL as a querystring, and that surely would need URL-encoding before trying to send it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode the URI using `encodeURIComponent` so that the parameter is treated as input. Try the below

```
function runPagespeed() {        
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.async = true;
        var query = [
            'url=' + encodeURIComponent(URL_TO_GET_RESULTS_FOR),
            'strategy=' + strategy,
            'callback=runPagespeedCallbacks',
            'key=' + API_KEY,
        ].join('&');
        s.src = API_URL + query;
        document.head.insertBefore(s, null);
    }
```